# Core Plot - How to convert touch point to plot point in a plot space with log axis

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I have a scatter plot with a linear y axis and logarithmic x axis, all of which works great.  But when I try to convert a touch point into the plot space coordinates, I'm having problems.

I have seen something like the following suggested various places:

```
- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceUpEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)space;

CPTScatterPlot *scatterPlot = [[[plotSpace graph] allPlots] objectAtIndex:0]; 
CGPoint plotAreaPoint = [[plotSpace graph] convertPoint:point toLayer:scatterPlot];

NSLog(@"PlotAreaPoint : %.1f, %.1f", plotAreaPoint.x, plotAreaPoint.y);

NSDecimal dataPoint[2];
NSDecimalNumber *xCoordinate, *yCoordinate;

[plotSpace plotPoint:dataPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:plotAreaPoint];

xCoordinate = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:dataPoint[0]];
yCoordinate = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:dataPoint[1]];

NSLog(@"DataPoint : %.1f, %.1f", [xCoordinate floatValue], [yCoordinate floatValue]);

return YES;
}
```

When I run this, plotAreaPoint seems correct, and yCoordinate is correct.  xCoordinate is correct if I tap at the left edge (5.0) or right edge (500.0), but behaves like a linear axis if I tap in the middle.  If I tap in the very middle, I get 250.0 or so, instead of 50.0.  Am I missing something, or is there another way to do this?

Thanks, Tim

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug. Please report it on the [Core Plot issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).